# Is there a way to alter the graph based on mouse cursor hovering over an option in a dropdown?

Tags: python, hover, plotly-dash

I am trying to create an interactive dropdown that would affect on the graph on hover, not on click (i.e. display changes as soon as user moves the cursor over one of the options). The problem seems inverse to the lots of Dash examples where user hovers the mouse over the graph to display the text in some text field or a popup.
I hoped to use dcc.Dropdown but any another object would do if the dropdown doesn't have the needed functionality. Actually, I'd appreciate any advice on non-graphical objects (dropdowns, tables, tabulators) which implement some kind of hover/hoverData event.

An example taken from here: https://dash-example-index.herokuapp.com/getting-started

It's a simple dropdown that changes the bar plot color once the user *clicks* on the dropdown option. I'd like to do the same on *hover* (so the bar plot will be changing colors in real time as the user moves the cursor over the options in the dropdown menu).

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H4("Interactive color selection with simple Dash example"),
        html.P("Select color:"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown",
            options=["Gold", "MediumTurquoise", "LightGreen"],
            value="Gold",
            clearable=False,
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input("dropdown", "value"),
)
def display_color(color):
    fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=["a", "b", "c"], y=[2, 3, 1], marker_color=color))
    return fig


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```